# XamarinAndriodPackage failed to load

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin, package

I have recently installed Xamarin into my Visual Studio 2013. Whenever I try creating a new project, I get this error.

**XamarinAndriodPackage failed to load**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3CNA.png

Can anyone please let me know the reason for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the Visual Studio component cache, this issue tends to come up with Android in particular:

https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md